# Is it possible to set up multiple schedules for a BigQuery scheduled query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking for a way to set up multiple schedules for a BigQuery scheduled query.

I'd like the scheduled query to run every Monday at 9:00 and the 1st of every month at 09:00.

something like: [every monday 09:00, 1 of month 09:00]

I've tried the custom schedule functionality and read through the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#formatting_the_schedule

[Screen shot of Custom Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVEb0.png)

I don't think this is feasible.

I was wondering if anyone has done something like this.

1. Looked through the recommended documentation, but don't think it's possible.